# CSS descendent selector to get all elements with a certain attribute, ignoring any that are descendents of an element with that same attribute

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using element attributes to identify a tree-like structure in the DOM and each node that branches looks after its children. It does so by searching descendents of the node in the DOM and checking for the attribute that identifies another node. It needs to do this since the child nodes might be several layers deeper in the DOM.

I'm currently doing this with the following JS:

```
const directChildNodes = [...nodeElement.querySelectorAll(`[tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"]`)]
  // filter all results where the current node is the closest parent
  .filter((el: Element) =>
    el.parentElement?.closest(`[tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"]`) === this.host.nativeElement);
```

This works, but is not very efficient as it grabs all elements with the attribute and then filters out ones that don't identify the current node as the closest parent. I would ideally be able to achieve this in the CSS selector.

I've tried the following selector but this does not seem to work:

```
nodeElement.querySelectorAll(
  `[tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"]:not([tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"] [tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"])`
)]
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks!

Comment: `.children` for all direct descendants of an element.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [`:scope` pseudo class](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-scope-pseudo):

```
nodeElement.querySelectorAll(':scope > [tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"]')
```

It's not supported in IE but it's supported in [most browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ascope).

Comment: Elements with the 'tree-node-name' attribute are not going to be direct children of the node, so the '>' selector does not work for this

Comment: Your comment got me looking more into the :scope pseudo class and I think I found a way to do it using that, not very pretty though: `querySelectorAll(':scope [tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"]:not(:scope [tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"] [tree-node-name="${this.treeName}"])')`

Comment: You're right, that's a mouthful! I confess that even after reading your question carefully 2 or 3 times I was struggling to fully visualise what you were describing, so apologies for my solution not being quite what you were after. Creating a fiddle for it might garner some more useful responses.

Comment: That's fair, I've been struggling to articulate the problem well enough to find anything online that helps, hence me asking a question in the hopes the answer found me! Messing with the `:scope` class seems to imply that even though the querySelectorAll is scoped to the element it runs from, adding a `:not()` selector will apply globally, so popping `:scope` in the `:not()` is the way to keep everything in reference to the element I'm searching from. Might not be the prettiest selector in the world but it does what I want!